# Why does the following case statement not work in the following loop?

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

Currently, I am writing a loop for a process that goes down a list of data and does certain things. I would like to use case statements to accomplish this.

What is wrong with my code? Is something wrong with my syntax?

```
Select Case me!Type

Case Me!Type Like "*Raytheon*"
    Do Until myParts.EOF
        rst_tbl_JString.New
        rst_tbl_JString!Code = CodeString
        rst_tbl_JString!Quantity = 1
        rst_tbl_JString!Part = myParts!Part
        rst_tbl_JString!Description = myParts!Description
        rst_tbl_JString!Amount = myParts!Amount
        rst_tbl_JString!Total = myParts!Amount
        rst_tbl_JString.Update
        Debug.Print JString!Part & " NEW "
        myParts.MoveNext
    Loop

End Select
```

Comment: What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: Issue is the use of LIKE. paxdiablo answer covers that.

Comment: Both loops seem to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to:

```
Select Case me!Model
    Case Me!Model Like "*Everflo*"
        do something
```

The expression in the `case` is meant to be checked against the object in the `select`. Unfortunately, the expression in your `case` is a *boolean* value (is something like something else), so will be unlikely to match any value in `me!Model`. What you effectively have is:

```
If me!Model = (Me!Model Like "*Everflo*")
    do something
```

The use case for `select/case` tends to be more of the form:

```
Select Case me!Model
    Case "Everflow"
        do something
```

so that the `case` expression can be correctly matched against the `select`object.

I think the best solution in this case (since you're doing "looks like" rather than "is equal to" comparisons) is just to revert to a simpler conditional construct:

```
If Me!Model Like "*Everflo*"
    do something
ElseIf Me!Model Like "*Platinum*"
    do something else
End If
```

Comment: ...or change to `Select Case True`

Comment: @Tim, that's another solution but I can't see that it adds much to the `if/elseif` method. It sort of flies in the face of `select-case` testing a variable against a set of values. I suppose it has the advantage of being the MNC (minimum necessary change) to get the code working but I think it would be hard to understand *why* it was done that way six months from now. We don't want to give Remy even *more* fodder for https://thedailywtf.com/ :-)